# pySerial not working on Python3.2.2

Tags: python, pyserial

I installed the 32 bit version of Python 3.2.2 and want to get the pySerial package to work. I most definitely have the pyWin32 package install but still when I try to import serial it gives me this error

```
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from serialwin32 import *
ImportError: No module named serialwin32
>>>
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you installed the correct [package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyserial/files/pyserial/2.5/pyserial-py3k-2.5.win32.exe/download)?

Comment: of pywin32? Yes. I think it just doesn't install otherwise.

Comment: and just to be clear, I installed pywin32-216.1.win32-py3.2.exe

Comment: try to uninstall it and use the one i posted

Answer (score 0):

Search around in your C:/Python32/Lib/site-packages/serial/. See if you can find a file named serialwin32. If not, you should try uninstalling pywin32 and reinstalling it.